# Return value at odd index within a list, challenge

Tags: python

Hey so i've got a simple challenge.

I need to return all values at an odd index position in a given array so an example would be
in: t=[3,5,2,6,2]
return p=[5,6]

The problem is when i enter my code it doesn't even compile on my IDE!
the error is 
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
please help
my code is:

```
def Odds(items):

    count = 0
    for i in items:
        if count%2!=0:
         odd_items = [items[count]]
        count=count+1
    return odd_items

def what(Odds):
    for i in Odds(0,len(Odds)):
        print (i)

Odds(items=[4,4,4,4])
what(Odds)
```

Comment: use a * to unpack the list and then try to debug.

Comment: `Odds(0,len(Odds))` - you use the same identifier for two different things. That cannot work

Comment: You're using the same variable for your function name and parameter to the other function

Comment: You're calling `Odds(items=[4,4,4,4])`, but you aren't saving the returned list object.  You need to save the result, and then pass that result into `what()`.

Comment: Others have mentioned the fact that you're using the same name twice, I think it's important to add that it's a bad name at that. Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
def what(Odds):
    for i in Odds(0,len(Odds)):
        print (i)

Odds(items=[4,4,4,4])
what(Odds)
```

Odds is a function, not an object. You can't iterate over a function, unless it has an iterator like a generator. In this case, you are trying to loop over a regular function.

This can be fixed extremely easily, by assigning the result of the Odds function to a list, and passing the list to the "what" function.

```
odd_list = Odds([4,4,4,4])
what(odd_list)

def what(odd_list):
    for odd_index in odd_list:
        print(odd_index)
```